# MYSQL QUERY if exists then get that specific column value and compare with new value

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, database-trigger

I am trying to compare a new value with the existing value from data based in a SQL statement, i.e. go to table get the specific value and check if the value is greater then the new value then update some other table, else do nothing.

My problem is that i am not able to convert the query value as a string to compare in a if statement.

My code:

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE   Id =NEW.Id and  time = NEW.time ORDER BY price ASC LIMIT 1)) THEN  

        IF (price <  NEW.price) THEN
//----------^^^^^^----------------- there is one column in table_1 not able to convert it to string to check in if statement///

            UPDATE historical SET low_price = NEW.price  WHERE  id =NEW.Id and date_time = NEW.time;  

        END IF;
    END IF;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If price is a column in table_1, you can move the second if condition to the first if condition.

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE   Id =NEW.Id and  time = NEW.time and price <  NEW.price ORDER BY price ASC LIMIT 1)) THEN  

        UPDATE historical SET low_price = NEW.price  WHERE  id =NEW.Id and date_time = NEW.time;  

END IF;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply i tried but it is like i want to that value in a string as i use two operations in is > and the one is < at that time its getting confused and creating a problem

Comment: " WHERE (price as varchar) <  NEW.price ORDER BY price ASC LIMIT 1 "

Comment: thanks for the reply i change my database data type to float and is working fine now